# Como ordenar um JSON por ordem decrescente?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um valor JSON que quero ordenar ele por ordem decrescente (Acho que no exemplo vai dar pra entender).

### Exemplo:

```
var json = {
    'um': {
        'cont': '5'
    },
    'dois': {
        'cont': '10'
    }
    ...
};
```

Então no caso, ele deve ser ordenado pelo valor 'cont' de cada *filho* do **json**.

No exemplo usei valores fixos, mas no código que vou usar vai ter muito mais filhos no **json** e os valores cont vão ser diferentes também.

Acho que deu pra entender, mas no final o valor deve ser: ['dois', 'um'];

Comment: Duas observações para orientar futuros visitantes desta pergunta: 1) isso aí não é JSON, é um objeto literal JavaScript (JSON seria a serialização disso como string); 2) objetos em js não são ordenados, você precisa de um array, como indicado na resposta do Miguel Angelo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode escrever uma função de comparação e passar como parâmetro do método sort do array.

Exemplo:

```
function comparer(a, b) {
    if (a.cont < b.cont)
        return -1;

    if (a.cont > b.cont)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

arr.sort(comparer);
```

Mas no caso, o json teria de ser um array, ao invés de um objeto.

**EDIT** fiz um fiddle de exemplo:

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yQa6m/3/)

**Referência**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Já utilizei [essa](http://hugoware.net/Projects/jlinq) biblioteca para ordenar e também para filtros, em arrays javascript (JSON).

Só não sei se no seu caso você pode mudar esse seu objeto para um array, para ai sim poder ser ordernado.

Se puder usar um array, essa é uma ótima abordagem.

Essa biblioteca [JLinq](http://hugoware.net/Projects/jlinq) é muito boa, nunca tive problemas com ela.

Ela trabalha com vários níveis hierárquicos do objecto JSON, e já implementa o `comparer` proposto pelo @Miguel.